# Starting kivy GUI app from terminal

Tags: python, user-interface, graphics, pygame, kivy

I recently installed python, pygame and kivy on Ubuntu 14.04LTS, I want to create a GUI that will run on a 10" capacitive touchscreen(haven't arrived yet). I managed to start the kivy hello world app with lightdm running, but I want to start it without ubuntu's GUI running, from standard terminal mode. But it says that 'Unable to get a Window, abort'.
How do I make a GUI that runs from terminal mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3331769/2469283 this is possible, but maybe kivy would need modification to do it, I'm not sure. Probably you'd need a custom window provider and maybe other stuff, as sdl2 etc. probably need X11.

Also, you don't need pygame any more, kivy has switched to sdl2.