# Python GUI toolkit inside Cygwin without X?

Tags: python, cygwin, xserver

Which Python GUI toolkit works inside Cygwin without X?

I installed both Tkinter and PyQt and they both require an X server. I would like to avoid running X but I do want to write a GUI around some Python code that's running in a Cygwin environment.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create an `OpenGL` application without initializing any automatic stuff within the library doing the `GL` calls. Most libraries instantiate a lot of `GL` objects for your convenience.. This is BAD for you. For instance `Pyglet` might work or `PyOpenGL`. `PyGame` would probably not work because of this reason. And most `GUI` libraries would also probably not work. You're working on a lower level program here and most `GUI` libraries (like Tkinter) would utelize the window manager to do stuff.

You need to call `eglGetDisplay`, `eglInitialize`, `eglCreateContext` and `eglMakeCurrent` in that order. This would make the need for a composit or window manager useless.

I'm no expert in the field and i'm SURE someone with better GL understanding could clarify the perfect steps to do this.

Found this question which explains it a little better, and also mentions the above `GL` calls: [OpenGL without X.org in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326641/opengl-without-x-org-in-linux)