# How to remove/disable glXCreatePbuffer in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, opengl, x11

I am trying to debug an opengl error that i have and i decided to use Nvidia Linux Graphics Debugger. My laptop has Nvidia Optimus but i manged to fix everything to make things work with dGPU using Fedora 22.

I am new to Linux developing and I tend to use wrappers when it comes to doing something because I started developing the same project in windows and linux at the same time. I find it easyer for some small things to use windows compared to linux but I would like to more and stay there. :D

When i try to capture a frame with Linux Graphics Debugger  I get this error.

Detected unsupported operations that may cause errors or a crash during capture.
First seen unsupported operation: glXCreatePbuffer

I did some googleing and i found out what is the operation. I get the same error with all applications that use OpengGl.

My problem is how to disable this. I am using SDL2 GLEW and FreeGlut.

Comment: What is "Linux OpenGL Debugger"? Do you mean [NVIDIA Linux Graphics Debugger](https://developer.nvidia.com/linux-graphics-debugger)?

Comment: How did you fixed that?

Comment: I edited the question to fix debugger name. Sorry.  I still can't fix it. I have no idea how to get rid of all Xorg/Xserver  opengl calls. If i can then i will probably be able to use the debugger. The gDEBugger has some issues with libraries and has Sigterm. I couldn't fix that either.

Comment: Well, does this warning really hurt? Maybe you could just ignore it? Linux OpenGL tools are in embryonic state comparing to Windows tools. Sometimes they doesn't work as expected.

Comment: The problem is that in order to render something you need a window system anyway (i.e. X11 or Wayland). You might try EGL [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326641/opengl-without-x-org-in-linux) to see if it runs without warnings. It will take much more effort than just initializing SDL, GLEW and GLUT, not sure if it's worth those efforts. I think that unless it really crashes as promised, you should ignore this warning.

Comment: The application runs but when i want to try and capture the frame and see what is going one it crashes Avid is OpenGL debugger. Yes i know a bit how the linux graphics stack works but i just cant find a way to bypass those calls. Even glxgears has the same problem with frame capturing.

Comment: One more thing. I would like to know how AAA games use direct graphics API calls without any wrapper. That might help me find the problem and learn more.

Comment: This is getting just harder since i have optimus tech in my laptop. I might try and use PRIME instead of Bumblebee. Check the last slide https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://keyj.emphy.de/files/linuxgraphics_en.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjajdH6qoPKAhVU2WMKHQQQB7AQFgg0MAc&usg=AFQjCNH33lZ8braWTG70vACbv3pZDiPkQA&sig2=_dTfZ4I7vmNfz3XFiRXGPQ

Comment: Make sure you are running on Nvidia GPU. Call [`glGetString()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetString.xhtml). To bootstrap OpenGL without 3rd party frameworks, check [opengl.org](https://www.opengl.org/) and [opengl.org/documentation](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/). Alternatively you may browse source code of any open-source application or framework (such as SDL or FreeGLUT that you are using) and modify them for your needs.

Comment: In addition you must make sure, that the `libGL.so` your program uses matches the graphics driver configured in the X11 server. Linux cross-vendor multi GPU OpenGL support is nonexistant, save for running an all Mesa/DRI setup.

Comment: the whole problem is that im using Xorg to create opengl context.if i want to get rid of any xorg calls i have to figure out how to create an opengl context without using any Xorg. I will need the xorg window but i have to create 2 context and then switch them like frame buffer.