# PyOpenGL headless rendering

Tags: opengl, glfw, headless, pyopengl

I'm using PyOpenGL+glfw for rendering.

When trying to do the same on a headless machine (e.g a server) `glfw.init()` fails:

```
glfw.GLFWError: (65544) b'X11: The DISPLAY environment variable is missing'
Fatal Python error: Couldn't create autoTLSkey mapping
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I found some information about headless rendering, but only when using OpenGL directly and not through python

EDIT: I understand that maybe glfw isn't able to support it. A solution without glfw, but with something else might also work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to use xvfb for a virtual framebuffer.

The problem is that the glfw that is installed in Ubuntu using `apt-get install libglfw3 libglfw3-dev` is old and unfit, so we need to compile it from source.

Here is a full working docker example:

```
docker run --name headless_test -ti ubuntu /bin/bash

# Inside the ubuntu shell:
apt update && apt install -y python3 python3-pip git python-opengl xvfb xorg-dev cmake
pip3 install pyopengl glfw
mkdir /projects
git clone https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git /projects/glfw
cd /projects/glfw
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON .
make
export PYGLFW_LIBRARY=/projects/glfw/src/libglfw.so
xvfb-run python3 some_script_using_pyopengl_and_glfw.py
```

And here is the base of PyOpenGL code to use it:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import glfw

glfw.init()
# Set window hint NOT visible
glfw.window_hint(glfw.VISIBLE, False)
# Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context
window = glfw.create_window(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, "hidden window", None, None)
# Make the window's context current
glfw.make_context_current(window)
```

Answer (score 3):

GLFW does not support headless OpenGL at all.

https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/context.html#context_offscreen

> GLFW doesn't support creating contexts without an associated window.

This isn’t an unusual limitation, the problem is that the normal way to create an OpenGL context is by using the X server. There are now alternatives using EGL, which is relatively new. You will need to use an EGL wrapper for Python.

See: [OpenGL without X.org in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326641/opengl-without-x-org-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use OpenGL without a display environment on linux(eg. x server) the best approach is to use `EGL`. what EGL does is it separate OpenGL context management from windowing system, so it let you create context without a displaying window.

If you are using Nvidia graphics card, you have to install proprietary driver in order to use it. along with the driver there is a library called `GLVND` this is a library which include `EGL` your app need to linked against.

Please refer to following links to learn how to use `EGL`:

[Pro Tip: Linking OpenGL for Server-Side Rendering](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/linking-opengl-server-side-rendering/)

[EGL Eye: OpenGL Visualization without an X Serve](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/egl-eye-opengl-visualization-without-x-server/)

PS. If your EGL api cannot find any devices, you probably linked wrong EGL library, the EGL library must match the driver.