# Mesa3D Without X

Tags: linux, mono, opengl-es-2.0, directfb, linux-from-scratch

I've spent the past 2 days searching this topic and I haven't found any up-to-date answers. I have a test project that is being based on the latest development [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/) (based on Kernel 3.4.1) but without installing the X server. And I'd like to build an application using Mono (or not) that will use OpenGL ES 2.x.

I could use Mesa3D but, from their site, it depends on X. I saw the DRI but it is still based on X. I stumbled upon the [DirectFB](http://www.directfb.org/) with DirectFBGL but the later is about 8 years old...

So the question : Is there a way to run OpenGL ES 2.x without X on a Linux kernel 3.4.1 using Mono (or not)?

EDIT 1 : I am targeting, for now, x86 or x64 PC. So is it wise to use OpenGL ES?

Comment: Or is using Qt Embedded with OpenGL ES 2.x a viable solution?

Comment: Just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036650/using-opengl-without-x-window-system) but it is only in software. Is it possible to have hardware acceleration or not?